# Excel vba user defined function filtering of multidimensional array; more efficient alternative to looping?

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array, user-defined-functions

I would like to figure out of there is a more efficient way of doing the following in excel:

I have a table in the following format detailing rental activity for ~75 different pieces of construction equipment (~5000 total lines):

```
equipment_id | customer_name | rental_start | rental_end | daily_rate  
Tractor A  |  Customer 1  |  12/1/2018  |  3/1/2019  |  $76.28  
Tractor A  |  Customer 2  |  3/19/2019  |  05/15/2019  |  $66.85  
Tractor A  |  Customer 1  |  7/15/2019  |  11/5/2019  |  $72.18  
Tractor B  |  Customer 3  |  8/1/2018  |  3/5/2019  |  $105.80
```

...and so on for all 75 or so pieces of equipment

This rental activity then drives quarterly financial projections based on the number of days each piece of equipment is rented in a given fiscal quarter. I am currently using the user defined functions below to:

1. take an equipment ID and the relevant fiscal period (e.g. Tractor A for the period 1/1/2019 to 3/31/2019)
2. iterate through the entire ~5000 line activity table for rows for Tractor A
3. calculate the number of days overlap between the fiscal period and rental start/end dates for each row that matches Tractor A
4. add to running tally of days overlapped and return after iterating through entire table

l

```
Function days_on_rent(equipment_id as String, period_start as Long, period_end as Long, rActivity as Range) as Long  
    Dim arrActivity() as Variant: arrActivity = rActivity  
    Dim rental_start as Long, rental_end as Long  
    Dim days_overlap as Integer  
    Dim i as Integer  
    For i = LBound(arrActivity) to UBound(arrActivity)  
        If arrActivity(i,1) = equipment_id Then  
            rental_start = arrActivity(i,3)  
            rental_end = arrActivity(i,4)  
            days_overlap = days_overlap + daysOverlap(period_start, period_end, rental_start, rental_end)  
        End If  
    Next i  
    days_on_rent = days_overlap  
End Function
```

Where daysOverlap is a separate function:

```
Function daysOverlap(pd1_start as Long, pd1_end as Long, pd2_start as Long, pd2_end as Long) as Integer
    Dim j as Integer
    With WorksheetFunction
        j = .Max(0, .Min(pd1_end - pd2_start, pd1_end - pd1_start) - .Max(0, pd1_end - pd2_end))
    End With
    daysOverlap = j
End Function
```

And then a second function that basically does the same thing, just takes a weighted average of (days overlap) * (rental rate) for the average daily rental rate over the relevant period.

Because there is a line item for each piece of equipment in the model, the each function gets run (75 pieces of equipment) * (24 quarters) = 1800 times
2 functions per piece of equipment = 3600 iterative loops through the activity table per cycle

The seemingly more efficient solution would be something like the following:
(i) load the activity table from worksheet into an array once and store in memory
(ii) filter the in memory array based on equipment_id
(iii) then loop through the filtered array to find days overlap for the relevant period

However I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Any thoughts?

Comment: As VBA is slow, I would use an sql-query for that. (once you mastered sql, you can replace all of such stupid iterations  by a gast an easy to read query). Assuming you are not familiar with sql, you can reduce the number of iterations, by first filter data matiching wanted period and then calculate only on the relevant data (e.g row three (7/15 to 11/4)  is irrelevat for first quater of 2019).

Comment: You could also look at power query for this type of analysis.

Comment: Is your code slow?  If not then no need to worry about "efficiency"